# How to read the redirect target of an ASP.NET request

Tags: asp.net

For logging purposes i want to log the redirect target of the current request to a database. how can i read the readirect target of the current request. keep in mind that i do not want to log on every Response.Redirect. I want the logging to take place in a central location. this location might be Application_EndRequest. I have tried to read the Repsonse.Headers collection to read the location header but is is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Application_EndRequest event, you can read the following two properties on your Response object:

Response.StatusCode will be set to 302 on redirects.
Response.RedirectLocation will be set to the URL where the browser will be redirecting.

Comment: Ok i guess this answers my question (which i have asked incompletely as i now notice). I have posted another one which is slightly different. I think this is more in line with the stackoverflow guidelines. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288077/how-to-read-all-http-headers-that-asp-net-sends-to-the-client

Answer (score 0):

Can you "invert" problem?
I mean property HttpRequest.UrlReferrer - can expose where you came from, so you could filter pages where UrlReferrer = 'login page' and log them to DB