# How to read all HTTP-Headers that ASP.NET sends to the client?

Tags: asp.net

For logging purposes i want to read ***all*** HTTP-Headers which are sent to the client anywhere in my application in order to log them to the database. However the ***Location-header is always missing*** on redirects. maybe there are even more missing that i will never know about. How can i get all headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues surrounding accessing the Headers collection of an HttpResponse object. Basically you need to be running IIS7 in "integrated pipeline mode".  If you can do this, you could simply take a look at the Response.Headers collection at the appropriate time.  Try something like this in your Global.asax file:

```
 protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var header in Response.Headers)
        {
            // Log to database
            insertIntoDatabase(header.ToString())
        }
    }
```

If you're not running IIS7... then you might be out of luck for an easy code solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from `Request.ServerVariables`.

Source: [Developer's Home](http://www.developershome.com/wap/detection/detection.asp?page=readHeader).

Comment: i want the headers that are sent to the client, not the ones received. also, i am usign asp.net.

Comment: Request.ServerVariables("ALL_HTTP"). From http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

Comment: i want the headers that are sent ***to the client***... Also i am not using ASP.

Comment: @mcandre i think that should be `Request.ServerVariables["ALL_HTTP"]`

Answer (score -2):

If you're desperate for them, you could capture them through a proxy. Though I don't exactly see why you'd want to do this.